# android app unable run in Motorola droid

Tags: android

Hi i am new to android. i developed an android app using 2.1 version in eclipse Ganymede. 
i used SQLite data base to store data and it will show the stored values when loading page My app is running perfectly in Sony Ericsson Xperia but it was not working in motorola droid which is having os Android 2.1 i dont know what is the cause. is there need to give any special permissions in manifest file to run app in droid or other mobile comapanies or any other issue occured by using the SQLite database?

Please respond for my request

Comment: You need to provide us some more information. What is the failure? How is it not working? Is there any logcat output? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, there's nothing about SQLite databases that requires any permission.  I have a published app in the market that uses a database and requests no permissions.  I also happen to know it runs fine on the original Droid because that's the phone I carry.